# CakePHP 3: Prevent partially rendered view from appearing when error is rendered

Tags: cakephp-3.0

In /Template/Error/ I modified error400.ctp and eror500.ctp to use the default layout when debugging is switched off.

This works fine. But if an error does not occur in the code of the controller's action, but in the view (e.g. due to queries that are executed only as soon as needed in the view), then the error page contains the part of the original action's view that was rendered, and then the html code of the layout and contents for displaying the error:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="/index">
<div class="box-normal">
    <select>…</select>
    <!-- the error occurs after the next </div>,
         and after that the output of the error page
         starts with <!DOCTYPE html> -->
</div><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is of course invalid html, and also confusing for the user.

Is there any way to flush the output buffer before the error is rendered so that any parts of views that were already rendered are discarded?

Comment: What type of error is that, and what's your exact CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`)?

Comment: For testing I created a query with the query builder and deliberately made an error in one of the conditions. I then set that query as a view variable. In the view there is a foreach iterating through the query variable.

CakePHP version is 3.4.1.

Comment: I should probably have been a little more clear about what I ment with "type of error". What I ment was, is it a warning, a syntax error, an exception, etc...? Also are you using [**the pre 3.3 dispatcher**](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.2.6/webroot/index.php#L33), or [**the new middleware stack**](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.4.1/webroot/index.php#L33)?

Comment: If I switch debugging on, an exception is thrown (InvalidArgumentException) and displayed for this error i placed in the query builder.
I also tried to see what happens if I insert a syntax error in the view file somewhere in the middle, but in that case nothing of the original view is rendered (only the error itself, which is the expected behaviour).
We are using the new middleware stack.

Comment: I can't reproduce it, error pages are shown just fine with debug disabled...